# How to achieve this two loops in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop

```
my_list = ['ab', 'abc', 'abcd']

for i=0; i<len(my_list); i++

    for j=i+1; j<len(my_list); j++:

        print(my_list[i], my_list[j])
```

I need two loops like above (in Java or C++) to compare elements with each other. How to do this similarly in Python? I was trying to do this, but it didn't work:

```
for index, value in enumerate(my_list, start=0):
   for index2, value2 in enumerate(my_list, start=1):
    print(value, value2)
```

It turns out that the outcome are not the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could compare each element in the list using combinations in itertools which generates all possible combinations:

```
import itertools
for a, b in itertools.combinations(mylist, 2):
    compare(a, b)
```

You could also try the traditional way using your code snippet:

```
for index1, value1 in enumerate(my_list):
    for index2, value2 in enumerate(my_list[index1+1:]):
        print(value1, value2)
```

Comment: It's strange that even if "start=index1+1", value2 still starts at the '0' index. Why is that?

Comment: If you are interested on getting the indices on ```a``` and ```b``` instead of values directly, you could do also ```for a, b in combinations(range(len(my_list)), 2)```

Comment: The problem is when we do 'start=1' the values are getting enumerated from 1 to len(my_list)+1. When we print the indices in the second loop it goes from 2 to 4 instead of 1 to 3. Hence we need to either slice before enumerating or use range.

Comment: I am editing my answer with  range.

Comment: "value2 still starts at the '0' index. Why is that?" Because that's just how `enumerate` is defined. The `start` parameter only changes the number that gets paired up with that index, not the underlying sequence.

Answer (score 5):

You can slice the list using enumerate, but this can be memory intensive depending on the size of the lists.

```py
for index1, value1 in enumerate(my_list):
    for index2, value2 in enumerate(my_list[index1+1:]):
        print(value1, value2)
```

You can also do the same code similar to the C code.

```py
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(my_list)):
        print(my_list[i], my_list[j])
```

Comment: In your first solution, you can skip the `enumerate` in the nested for-loop as you're not using the resulting index.

Comment: wouldn't `range(i, len(my_list))` be `range(i+1, len(my_list))`?

Comment: @Tyger yes you are correct

Comment: @Jmonsky also your `enumerate(my_list[index1:])` needs to be `enumerate(my_list[index1+1:])`

Answer (score 0):

Like this :?

```
    my_list = ['ab', 'abc', 'abcd']
    for idx in range(len(my_list)):
       for ele in my_list[:idx] + my_list[idx+1:]: 
          print(my_list[idx], ele)
```

Comment: `for ele in range(idx+1,len(my_list))`

Comment: Cool, Thansk @prashantrana